# Regex to remove <> from column

Tags: regex, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a column with name and email id like

```
Column A 

ABX <ABX@gmail.com>
hfgfg <shantanu @gmail.com>
```

I Want to use a regex to only retrieve the name and exclude the <> along with email idfrom the above column.

Regex in SQL query.

I tried

```
SELECT REPLACE('s <abc@gmail.com>', SUBSTR('s <abc@gmail.com>', instr('(', 's <abc@gmail.com>'), LENGTH('s <abc@gmail.com>') - instr(')', reverse('s <abc@gmail.com>')) - instr('(', 's <abc@gmail.com>') + 2), '')
FROM dual;
```

Comment: It isn't clear if you want to exclude the angle brackets, or those and the email address. This is fairly simple though - what have you tried and what problems did you have?

Comment: @AlexPoole - Thanks for correcting i have added my query and edietd the question. Pls up vote if you find it valid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use regular expressions; either remove everything from first opening angle bracket, optionally trimming any remaining spaces as well:

```
select rtrim(regexp_substr('s <abc@gmail.com>', '[^<]*'), ' ') as name from dual;
```

Or replace the angle brackets and whatever is inside them, and any immediately preceding whitespace, with null:

```
select regexp_replace('s <abc@gmail.com>', '\s?<.*>', null) as name from dual;
```

With some sample data:

```
with your_table(column_a) as (
  select 'Some Name <some.name@example.com>' from dual
  union all select 'SingleName <single@example.com>' from dual
)
select column_a,
  rtrim(regexp_substr(column_a, '[^<]*'), ' ') as name1,
  regexp_replace(column_a, '\s?<.*>', null) as name2
from your_table;

COLUMN_A                          NAME1           NAME2         
--------------------------------- --------------- ---------------
Some Name <some.name@example.com> Some Name       Some Name      
SingleName <single@example.com>   SingleName      SingleName
```

If you want the email address as well you could use:

```
select regexp_substr('s <abc@gmail.com>', '([^<>]*)', 1, 3) as email from dual;
```

... though there might be a better way. Demoing that too:

```
with your_table(column_a) as (
  select 'Some Name <some.name@example.com>' from dual
  union all select 'SingleName <single@example.com>' from dual
)
select column_a,
  rtrim(regexp_substr(column_a, '[^<]*'), ' ') as name1,
  regexp_replace(column_a, '\s?<.*>', null) as name2,
  regexp_substr(column_a, '([^<>]*)', 1, 3) as email
from your_table;

COLUMN_A                          NAME1      NAME2      EMAIL               
--------------------------------- ---------- ---------- ---------------------
Some Name <some.name@example.com> Some Name  Some Name  some.name@example.com
SingleName <single@example.com>   SingleName SingleName single@example.com
```

Comment: Thanks. this worked. Is there a way to get the email address that is extract the string between bracket from this oclumn by regex ?

Comment: @divya.trehan573 - I've added a way to do that.

Answer (score -1):

Why don't you try something like this :

```
UPDATE table SET A=TRIM(SUBSTRING(A, 1, INSTR(A,'<')));
```

Comment: CHARINDEX in oracle?

Comment: Oups ! Thanks for the remark, you should look at the INSTR function. I edited the post.

Comment: It should be SUBSTR not SUBSTRING; and this will include the opening angle bracket.

Comment: @JonathanRotge -Thanks .. but this will not work.. this will only replace >

Comment: I want to remove the email address from teh column